# If $\operatorname{ker} T \neq \{0\}$, there is $S: V \rightarrow V$, $S\neq 0$, with $T \circ S = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T$ be linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow  V$ . If $\operatorname{ker}  T \neq \{0\}$, prove that there's a linear transformation $S:  V \rightarrow V$ such that $S$ is not the zero transformation but $T \circ S = 0$.

is there any sentence or a any direction that anyone can give me ? I have no clue what to do(I could prove that The second side will prove the $\operatorname{ker} T$ is not zero but i dont have any idea to prove the first side...}

Comment: Hi, please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  What do you mean you could prove the second side?  Do you mean you could prove the converse?  Please put some more detail about what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: hint: If $\ker T \neq \{0\}$ then there is $v\neq 0$ with $Tv = 0$.  Then if $Sx$ is a multiple of $v$, we have $TSx = 0$.  So you want to find $S$ so that $Sx$ is a multiple of $v$ for any $x$.

Comment: @JairTaylor than x is a linear combination of v ?

Comment: No. $x$ is an arbitrary vector in $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** $T \circ S = 0$ if and only if for every $x \in V$, $S(x) \in \ker T$.

**Hint 2:** For any vector spaces $U,V$ for which $U \neq \{0\}$ and $V \neq \{0\}$, there exists a linear transformation $S: U \to V$ with $S \neq 0$.

Comment: But I need to prove that if kerT is not zero : ToS = 0 and S is not the zero linear transformation

Comment: @Sababoni Your statement is not correct. You need to prove that if $\ker T$ is not zero, then **there exists a transformation $S$ such that** $T \circ S = 0$ and $S$ is not the zero linear transformation.

Comment: Then can I see that if S(x) is from ker T that means that ImS is not zero. and because S(x) is the image then x can't be zero too and because of that S:U->V is not the zero linear transformation?

Comment: @Sababoni The statement "if $S(x)$ is from $\ker T$ that means that $\operatorname{Im}S$ is not zero" is not correct. You'll have to be a bit more precise with your argument.

Comment: but if S(x) is from kerT that means that S(x) is not zero. Is that mean that x can be zero and still be ImS ?

Comment: @Sababoni Let's look at an example so that maybe you can see more concretely why your comments are incorrect. Take $V = \Bbb R^2$, and consider the maps defined by $S(x) = Ax$ and $T(x) = Bx$ with 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.
$$
The kernel of $T$ is the $x$-axis. If we consider the vector $x = (0,1)$, then we see that $S(x) \in \ker T$, and $S(x) = 0$.  So, it is not true that "if $S(x) \in \ker T$, then $S(x)$ is $0$". Also, yes: zero is an element of $\operatorname{Im}(S)$.

Comment: @Sababoni sorry, that should be $S(x) = Bx$ and $T(x) = Ax$.

Comment: then the point in the prove is that to assume that there's a space V which dont have the zero vector ( but have some 'neutral vector' ) and because the linear transformation to itself that mean's it's lienar transformation cant be the zero transformation ?

Comment: @Sababoni Maybe the problem we are having is one of language rather than ideas. Do you understand the difference between the sentences "$V$ does not have the zero vector" and "$V$ has a non-zero vector"?

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand the diffrence :(

Comment: @Sababoni I'm glad, that makes it clear why there was a misunderstanding. For example, consider the set $S = \{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)\}$. "$S$ does not have the zero vector" means that $\vec 0 \notin S$, which is false. "$S$ has a non-zero vector" means that there is an $x \in S$ with $x \neq 0$, this is true because $x = (1,0)$ is such a vector.

Comment: Thanks :) do you have any link to a document which prove your 2nd hint ( I haven't learned this prove ....)?